# Appling condition in lambda function in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, conditional-statements

I have a pandas data frame and creating new column out of existing column values with'-' separator
I am trying this below code its not working as expected.

```
data["{}_pid".format(granularity)] = data[config['compute_hierarchy'][granularity]].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep='-') if x.granularity != None, axis=1 )
```

ex: if i have column value as a,b,c then new column value is a-b-c and if any column value is null then lambda function should not execute

Comment: You can't do this within the `lambda`; if the `lambda` executes, it must return *something* (even if it's just returning some unmodified value, e.g. `lambda x: x.str.cat(sep='-') if x.granularity is not None else x.str`. Typically, you want to mask your inputs and outputs such that the `lambda` isn't invoked at all when you don't want to change anything; it's easy in `numpy`, but I don't know how much of that will translate to `pandas` `DataFrame`s.

Comment: what are your current `data[config['compute_hierarchy'][granularity]]` values?

Comment: Specifically, what is the data type of the values in the `data` columns you're looking to apply this lambda to (optionally)?

Answer (score 0):

"if" keyword "directly" (I'm being vague) in a lambda can only be part of a ternary operator.
So this lambda :

```
l1 = lambda x:  "yes" if x else "no"
```

is correct, while this one :

```
l2 = lambda x:  "yes" if x
```

is not.

If without else can be part of an expression in a list comprehension :

```
[print(a) for a in range(10) if a % 2]
```